# How to filter undesired elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, class, jquery-selectors

lets take for example two divs,

```
<div class="main right"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
```

And this jQuery snippet, as it follows:

```
$('.main').css('background-color','red');
```

This will change both divs background-color to red, as normal. I'd like to know how to change that color for the divs that have only "main" as class, not "main right",

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('.main:not(.right)').css('background-color','red');
```

Or:

```
$('.main').not('.right').css('background-color','red');
```

---

If had to more complicated conditions it can be done with `filter` function:

```
$('.main').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('value') == 2 && this.innerHTML.length < 50;
}).css('background-color','red');
```

It will filter out the result of `.main` and maintain only element which their `data-value` is 2 and their `innerHTML.length < 50`.

---

If you don't know what other classes could be to `main` but you want the elements which has only the `main` class.

```
$('.main').filter(function(){
    return $.trim(this.className) == 'main';
}).css('background-color','red');
```

Answer (score 1):

use the 'not()' selector.

`$('.main:not(.right))`
or like: `$('.main').not('.right')`

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you want to verify that "main" is the *only* class before you apply the style. You can do this with a quick regex test:

```
$('.main').filter(function(){
    return /^\s*main\s*$/.test(this.className);
}).css('background-color','red');
```

Comment: You could do it with `$.trim(this.className) == "main"`. Am I right?

Comment: @gdoron Yes you can do that, and it's actually even slightly faster :) http://jsperf.com/trim-vs-s-x-s

Comment: Thought so, I summed the Assembly actions for each option and found mine better. **:) LOL**. Thanks for the jsperf! +1