# Jquery class selector and hide()

Tags: jquery

```
$('.comment').hide(2000);
```

This fades hides the class comment after two seconds. Is there an easy way to prevent a div with class "comment" from fading by adding an extra class?

```
<div class="comment">This text hides</div>
<div class="comment nohide">This text should not hide</div>
```

Adding the nohide class didn't prevent it from hiding. I'll probably end up creating a new class, but thought I'd ask.

Comment: Already asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466940/how-to-filter-undesired-elements-with-jquery/10466957#10466957

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:not` selector to filter elements:

```
$('.comment:not(.nohide)').hide(2000);​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/M6zgw/

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
$('.comment.fadeable').hide(2000)
```

if possible. As it usually looks more straightforward than "not" option. `$(".x.y").hide()` applies `hide()` only to divs that have "x" and "y" classes.